# SQL Error [22018]: Invalid character string format for type java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT sum(cast (activity_count as decimal(10,2))) as "Sum"
from schema_name.table_name
where user_key like '%CAN%' 
or user_key like '%CA%'
or user_key like '%CFS%'
and activity_date = '2017-04-19'
and activity_name = 'Address Changes'
and activity_status = 'Processed'
```

The query runs OK if I use no `OR` operator but as soon as I'm trying to do that, I receive the following error:

> SQL Error [22018]: Invalid character string format for type
>   java.math.BigDecimal.   Invalid character string format for type
>   java.math.BigDecimal.
>       com.splicemachine.db.client.am.SqlException: Invalid character string format for type java.math.BigDecimal.

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: `where ( user_key like '%CAN%' ... or ...) and  activity_date = '2017-04-19' ...` (Will return the wanted rows, but not correct the case issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You need your parentheses in the right place:

```
SELECT sum(cast(activity_count as decimal(10,2))) as "Sum"
from schema_name.table_name
where (user_key like '%CAN%' or user_key like '%CA%' or user_key like '%CFS%') and
      activity_date = '2017-04-19' and
      activity_name = 'Address Changes' and
      activity_status = 'Processed';
```

Your `sum()` doesn't make that much sense.  Isn't `activity_count` already a number.  If not, why not?  Why would something called a "count" have two digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Thank you, the hint about parentheses was helpful.

Comment: The hint about parentheses was helpful. To answer your questions: activity_count column is VARCHAR. And you're right - I could have used INTEGER instead of DECIMAL but that is more like a precaution in my case.